# Parserror in AJAX request, form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm using an `AJAX` request to `submit` a `form` login.

```
$.post(url, {data: JSON.stringify( {obj: value} )}, 'json')
 .fail(function(){
    console.log(typeof arguments[0].responseText) //logs 'string'
    //console.log(JSON.parse(arguments[0].responseText)) // decommented logs "unexpected     token"
    console.log(arguments) 
 });
```

I'm getting

```
1: "parsererror"
2: SyntaxError
   message: "Unexpected token "
..
..
```

I've also set `header("Content-type: application/json")` but it did not solved the problem, 
I'm also using `json_encode` as server-side response.

I got `status: 200` and, it seems, the right `json` `responseText`. I don't know what else to do.

(do not flag this question as a duplicate, I did search over SO, none question solved my issue)

**EDIT**
Added `responseText`

**chrome**

```
responseText: "↵{"success":true,"error":false}"
```

**firefox**

```
"\r\n{"success":true,"error":false}"
```

**EDIT2**

```
json_encode(array( .. ))
```

introduce `\r\n` but I don't know why.

Comment: The url returns what? just 'string'? then its not a valid JSON

Comment: can you add `responseText` or firebug screen shot?

Comment: edited the question with the response text

Comment: use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json data first. Check that your json data is valid or not... it's sound that something in wrong in your json data.

Comment: I validated the `response` that I got in developer tools, network tab, and it seems to be valid.

Comment: `↵` can you see char in response text

Comment: I noticed that `json_encode` introduce `\r\n` , any thought on why?

Comment: try to use str_replace("\r\n", "", $jsondata) to remove aliens character's :)

Comment: json_encode not producing `\r\n` char, you have leaved above `new line` in your code. that buffer output comes in ajax response.

Comment: @Girish I did not understand, can you explain it clearly,  in an answer maybe?

Comment: @steo, see updated ansewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`↵` is unexpected char in response, please use `ob_start` function before json_encode function on server side.
`↵` this is `enter` key code, please remove from response

```
ltrim(json_encode($response_arr), "\r\n"); // this would be useful in php code
```

//

```
responseText: "↵{"success":true,"error":false}"
```

to

```
responseText: "{"success":true,"error":false}"
```

The issue in ajax response, see blow image for better understanding
[image]
`new line` case (red mark) will have in your server code.. if you can remove `new line` the issue will be resolved.

**Other solution**

remove header(`Content-type : application/json`) and use `jQuery.parseJSON(jQuery.trim(response))` in jQuery code.

ajax code

```
$.post(url, {data: JSON.stringify( {obj: value} )}, function(response){
      var data = jQuery.parseJSON(jQuery.trim(response));
      console.log(data);
})
 .fail(function(){
    console.log(typeof arguments[0].responseText) //logs 'string'
    //console.log(JSON.parse(arguments[0].responseText)) // decommented logs "unexpected     token"
    console.log(arguments) 
 });
```